# Javascript Newb: Show divs by class on radio click

Tags: javascript

Okay, obviously I'm new to javascript. I'm trying to use radio buttons to hide divs by class, my function needs to hide all the divs with either class name "p12" or "p34" when a single radio is clicked.

BUT

This is only working for all the p12 divs.... what am I missing to make both?..

```
if (document.getElementById('numbofextras0').checked == true) {
    for(i=0; i<100; i++) 
        document.getElementsByClassName('p12')[i].style.display = 'none';

    for(i=0; i<100; i++) 
        document.getElementsByClassName('p34')[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Not a very descriptive title, consider changing it.

Comment: Have you tried looking at a javascript debugger or plain simply checked if any errors occured?

Comment: Also, it looks like the problem is influenced by more than you are showing us, so you'd be better off giving us a working minimal sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't like you possibly going outside the range of what the `getElementsByClassName` returns (but then again, I haven't tested/checked what would happen). Try storing the results first, then looping through them.

```
var p12s = document.getElementsByClassName('p12');
for (var i = 0; i < p12s.length; i++) {
    p12s[i].style.display = "none";
}

var p34s = document.getElementsByClassName('p34');
for (var i = 0; i < p34s.length; i++) {
    p34s[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

This way, it loops over the exact amount of elements (you don't have hardcode `100` in) that each `getElementsByClassName` returns.

The main problem is that when you hardcode `100` in, it will always loop from 0 to 99. If `getElementsByClassName` returns less than 100 elements, trying to access that index will return undefined and throw an exception when you try to do something like `.style.display = "none";`. Or what if there's 160 elements returned? Only the first 100 will be modified. Making the call before the loop and storing the returned elements in a variable, then looping through that length, is the safe/correct way. The way you had it before, it was making a call to `getElementsByClassName` on every loop iteration - very inefficient - you only **need** to do it once!...and of course, hardcoding `100` wasn't the best way to loop through the elements. It was all the right idea, just not the right order. I mean, technically, you could've done something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('p12')[i];
    if (el) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

But like I said, calling `getElementsByClassName` on every loop iteration isn't very efficient.

Comment: Works perfectly! I can't thank you enough ianpgall! I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @Jasper Don't worry, it fixes it. When you loop through an array of elements past its length and try to access the element, it won't work, because it'll be undefined. The problem is hardcoding the 100, and always looping to it (when there may only be 5 elements with the class on the page).

Comment: you can pass more than one ids to document.getElementsByClassName() function to shorten your code lenght, pls check my answer

Comment: @AlagesanPalani Sorry, that's not what passing more than one class to the function means. Check my comment on your answer.

Comment: @ianpgall even your code does the same right? you are hiding all the elements with class id 'p12' in the first section, and 'p34' in the second section. are you doing anything different? am i missing something here?

Comment: @AlagesanPalani Nope. Using `'p12 p34'` grabs elements that have **both** classes. Using two separate calls for `'p12'` and `'p34'` separately grabs elements that have the class. That means your code will **only** match elements that are like this `class="p12 p34"`, when it needs to match elements that are like `class="p12"` **or** `class="p34"`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

```
document.querySelectorAll(".p12, .p34")
```

This won't work in older browsers if you care. But if you do, I'd rather recommend jQuery or something similar over vanilla JS.

Comment: Here is the browser support information for querySelectorAll: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Answer (score -1):

Try this code please:

```
if (document.getElementById('numbofextras0').checked == true) {
          var elems=document.getElementsByClassName('p12 p34')
          for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++) 
             elems[i].style.display='none';
        }
```

Comment: That's not correct. Using `'p12 p34'` means match all elements that have the class "p12" **AND** "p34", which is not what the OP seems to want. And if there were specific operations that need to occur on each type, you'd want to separate the call...but in this case, both sets of elements have the same thing done to them - hide them.

Comment: @ianpgall even your code does the same right? you are hiding all the elements with class id 'p12' in the first section, and 'p34' in the second section. are you doing anything different? am i missing something here?